# WPF: Is it possible to nest TreeView items with a binding expression?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, treeview

Lets say I have the following data:

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="Values">
  <x:XData>
    <folder name="C:">
      <folder name="stuff" />
      <folder name="things" />
      <folder name="windows">
        <folder name="system32" />
      </folder>
    </folder>
  </x:XData>
</XmlDataProvider>
```

How can I get that into a treeview?  I can't seem to grok hierarchical binding...

I know that I can get it in there in C# code, but I wanted to do it with a binding expression.

Comment: I've added a link to an article that should help you get this going using XAML only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**: Didn't see that you wanted to do this in XAML only. [This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/cbdb2420-1403-436f-aa7f-b1e3b1acb398) MSDN post should help you out.

`HierarchicalDataTemplate` isn't so bad if your data is already in a hierarchical form. Let's say you translate that XML data into a model class using code like this:

```
public partial class TreeViewHierarchy : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Folder> Folders
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public TreeViewHierarchy()
    {
        Folder system32 = new Folder() { Name = "system32" };
        Folder windows = new Folder() { Name = "windows", 
            Children = new ObservableCollection<Folder>() { system32 } };

        Folder things = new Folder() { Name = "things" };
        Folder stuff = new Folder() { Name = "stuff" };

        Folder c = new Folder() { Name = "C:",
            Children = new ObservableCollection<Folder>() { stuff, things, windows } };

        Folders = new ObservableCollection<Folder>() { c };

        InitializeComponent();

    }
}

public class Folder
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Folder> Children
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Then the XAML for your `TreeView` would be as simple as this:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpfApplication.TreeViewHierarchy"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="TreeViewHierarchy" Height="300" Width="300"
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

And the result:

[alt text http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/7841/treeviewhierarchy.png](http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/7841/treeviewhierarchy.png)

Comment: +1 It's worth highlighting the important part of the xaml is where you bind the 'ItemsSource' of the HierarchicalDataTemplate to the 'Children' collection of the Folder object... Great answer :)